# Questions about running a program (pygame)

Tags: pygame

I have installed pygame and I dont know how to allow my python to read it...

I do

```
# import modules
import os
import pygame
```

And I got this: `ImportError: No module named 'pygame'`

Comment: Did you install pygame?

Comment: Yes! Thanks for the help! I just dont know now how I can have python recognize it so I can use it :( Thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: Can you give us some information like what operating system and version of Python you are using?  Also, can you verify that pygame is in your Python installation's site-packages?

Comment: @Haz you are great! Windows 7 ultimate it says. I am a beginner I dont know how to check if it is in the installation site packages.. I guess that is part of my question. I just downloaded it. 
The python version is 3.32! thanks a bunch sorry I am beginner at this.

Comment: Make sure you match bit versions too. If you have python3 32bit you will need pygame-python3-32bit.

Comment: @monkey, I have downloaded the py3.2 pygame. What is the next step to have my program read it? Thanks

Comment: If you're using Windows, you should just get the executable pygame installer from the website; it'll be the easiest way to install it.  If it has been installed,  there should be a directory called `pygame` in your Python site-packages directory (probably something like 'C:/Python32/Lib/site-packages`)

Comment: Thanks :) I found it in the download folder.. so do I drag it into the python site directory?

Comment: Then... do I call it as above?

Comment: I tried the import after dragging it and it said...
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
would you mind please giving me a link to where I can download the right version?? ughhh thanks....

Comment: Do you have 32bit or 64bit python? (not the OS, but python version)  For 32bit you run https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads/pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py3.2.msi You don't have to move any folders around, it will install the package to the right folder. The only thing you have to worry about is if you have multiple python versions installed

Comment: Ok! reinstalled the 32 bit version...  then the link you suggested...
then wrote: import pygame
Still not working.. to bad.... I guess its not meant to be

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing something here. Download the correct package from the pygame website. it should be a .exe. Then, go to your downloads folder. Double-click on the file to run it and follow the on-screen prompts to install pygame. After you have done that, try importing pygame. You don't need to click-and-drag anything. just run the file you downloaded. Let me know if this works.

Assuming you have windows 32 bit, you would download these files:

python 2.7:

http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.5/python-2.7.5.msi

pygame for 2.7:

http://pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.1.win32-py2.7.msi

Comment: I did do this, what is the command for importing it... strange it is not working.. maybe I will try this again.
Could you give me a link for python and the equivalent pygame and I will download them again... thanks

Comment: you can import doing either `import pygame` or `from pygame import *` (make sure there are no caps)

Comment: I added a few links to my answer. What OS are you running?

Answer (score 0):

If you have run the pygame installer, them make sure your python script is not named pygame.
It is a common mistake made by beginners.

When you type

```
import pygame
```

the python interpreter first searches the path you are in, and if it does not find the module with the given name, it searches the modules folder. So if you have a file named pygame or your file is named pygame, change it to something else.